# fragment is not shown

Tags: android, android-fragments

i set on click on the card view when i click on the card view the fragment is shown on the activity i assume that but the fragment is not shown the onclick of cardview is working but fragment is not shown  i try alot but no solution i do not know why this happen. There is no error also but my fragment is not shown even no error Advance thanlks
here's code

```html
Activity

public class SubmitAddActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CallbackFromFragment {
  


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.submitadd_layout);
        
        findViewById(R.id.choose_category_layout).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("bullhead", "onClick: hellow rodl ");
                fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container,fragmentUsage);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                fragmentUsage.setTYPE(1);
            }
        });
        
                   submitbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        settingToolbar();

    }

   



    @Override
    public void setValues(int type, String value) {
    if(type==1)
    {
        fragmentTransaction.remove(fragmentUsage);
        category=value;
    }
    else if(type==2)
    {
        fragmentTransaction.remove(fragmentUsage);
        location=value;
    }

    }


}
```

Activity layout

```html
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/containerfragments"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.asad.taleembazar.activities.HomeActivity">

        
        <include
            layout="@layout/cardview_choose_category_submitadds"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            />
       

    </LinearLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/container"

            />
    </FrameLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

fragment

```html
public class SelectFragment extends Fragment implements com.asad.taleembazar.adpaters.callback {
    private SelectCategorySubmitAddAdapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
    CallbackFromFragment communication;
    int type;

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;



    public SelectFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_select_category_submit,container,false);
        arrayList.add("Cars");
        arrayList.add("Mobiles");
        arrayList.add("Bags");
        RecyclerView recyclerViewforsubmitadd = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_for_categoriessubmit);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerViewforsubmitadd.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerViewforsubmitadd.setHasFixedSize(true);
        adapter = new SelectCategorySubmitAddAdapter(arrayList);
        adapter.setOnClick(this);
        recyclerViewforsubmitadd.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }



    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        communication = (CallbackFromFragment) context;

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(int adapterPosition) {
        if(type==1)
        communication.setValues(1,arrayList.get(adapterPosition));
        else if(type==2)
            communication.setValues(1,arrayList.get(adapterPosition));

    }
public void setTYPE(int i)
{
    type=i;
}
}
```

Comment: You should really reduce this code to provide the minimal working example which demonstrates your problem. Remove everything else

Comment: it is reduced now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`match_parent` of your container `Framelayout` won't work inside your `ScrollView`. You can either set `android:fillViewport="true"` in your `ScrollView` or You can set a fixed height for your container.

Try below code

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/containerfragments"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context="com.asad.taleembazar.activities.HomeActivity">


              <include
                  layout="@layout/cardview_choose_category_submitadds"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  />


        </LinearLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/container"

            />
    </FrameLayout>

</ScrollView>
```